# Navigating from a login screen to home page on RN

Tags: react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I am learning RN, and as a part of my project, I am building an app that will take me to my toolbelt of items I will be making or have made such as animations.  I am currently struggling with the login component of it.  I am looking to login to my app so that it can take me to the homepage.  I am using asyncstorage. When I log in, nothing happens except it stays on the login page.  I have provided the lines of code as to how I have it built out. I really am just looking for something to get to the homepage on my simulator.  I won't be deploying it or anything as I am keeping it to myself, but if any of you have any recommendations for articles or videos on how to achieve this in a "simpler" fashion, I am open to that option as well.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonContainer}
          onPress={this._signInAsync}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", "abc");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("app");
  };
}
```

Comment: Try this `onPress={this._signInAsync()}` and let me know

Comment: No, `onPress` is expecting a function to be called, not the result of a function.

Comment: Please share your navigator setup and just to be sure you could log anything inside `_signInAsync()`.